# Visual Studio - Add Resource as Link (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am attempting to add a **linked resource** to my **C++ project** in **Visual Studio**. However when I select '*Add Existing Item*' and look for the '*Add as Link*' option from the '*Add*' button dropdown, it is not available.

However, I do see this option available for **.NET** projects.

Does this functionality not exist for **C++** in **Visual Studio 2010**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the default. You don't need a separate button.

If you want the file in your project folder, you put it there first.